# MySql PHP Connection issues

Tags: php, html, mysql, localhost

I am aware that this has already been posted but have tried the options available on here, so am forced to ask again...have been trying all sorts for weeks now...to no avail!

Have an account in cPanel, with a database in phpMyAdmin and am trying to return data to my website.

Initially, I kept getting errors connecting, and found that I hadn't set user privileges (am new to this).

Now I have sorted that, when I create a search in the text area and hit return, the Favicon spins around and goes back to the initial state.

I am so spun around with it all now, that I am unsure if its PHP, MYSQL, HTML etc. etc.

Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
$output=NULL;   
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //Connect to the database
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "jj3wg2td_wix", "Sebastian!16", "jj3wg2td_careerslist");
    $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
    //Query the database    
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM careers WHERE Job Title LIKE '%$search%'");
    if($resultSet->num_rows > 0){
        while($rows=$resultSet->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $jobTitle=$rows['Job Title'];
            $jobDesription=$rows['Job Description'];
            $salaryLow=$rows['Salary Low'];
            $salaryHigh=$rows['Salary High'];
            $output .="Job Title:$jobTitle<br />
                        Job Description:$jobDesription<br />
                        Salary Low:$salaryLow<br />
                        Salary High:$salaryHigh<br />
                        <br />";
         }
    }else{
        $output="No results";   
    }       
}
?>
```

This doesn't return "No Results" at all, just blank space.

I also have a PHP output after my search button code of:

`<?php echo $output; ?>`

Search button being:

```
<!--SEARCH BOX-->
    <div class="search-box">
        <form method="POST">
        <input class="search-txt" type="TEXT" name="search" placeholder="SEARCH CAREERS">
            <a class="search-btn" type="SUBMIT" name="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                        </form>
                            </div>
```

The 'Local Host' in phpMyAdmin states that the name', Localhost:3306 (have seen this issue a lot). So I have tried that, as well as just 'localhost....but nothing works at all now.

Apologies for my basic understanding in advance...and that you for any help!!!

Completely giving up!

Comment: If it's outputting nothing, that suggests `$_POST['submit']` is not set - you could add an 'else' for that scenario to check - does an `<a>` come in as a form field, or should it be a `<button>` or `<input type="button">`? In any case you should check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"` rather than the old way. You could `var_dump($_POST);` to see if it's set. You could add loads of `echo` statements so you can debug exactly how far through the PHP it gets.

Comment: Is there JS that sends the form request?

Comment: okay, give me some info first:  
1. Can u login into phpmyadmin using username and password?
2. Can u see the database which you've created in phpmyadmin?
pls answer the question as fast as possible...

Comment: When you get blank pages, open the Network tab in devtools and try your operation again. You can see what your php program sends to your browser. View Source also helps.

Comment: phpmyadmin is itself a php program to access MySQL and let you administer it. You connect to phpmyadmin with a web browser (maybe on localhost) and it connects to your MySQL server via port 3306. All this stuff has a LOT of moving parts; it's possible you don't understand them all quite yet. Be patient.

Comment: Complementing @user3783243, if there's no JS sending the request, action attribute is missing in form element.

Comment: Is that really your username and password in the paste? Guess you'' be needing to change those now.

Comment: @CarlosBazilio a form does not require an `action` as it will simply submit to the same url that it resides on. Default behavior of forms. Now, its better coding practice to always designate an `action` so there is no confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think your form was not submitting on click of `<a>`. So, you have to make such changes to submit your form first.

Solution 1 (With help of JS):

```
<div class="search-box">
  <form method="POST" id="searchForm">
    <input class="search-txt" type="TEXT" name="search" placeholder="SEARCH CAREERS">
    <a class="search-btn" onclick="document.getElementById('searchForm').submit()">
       <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Solution 2: Use `<button>` as a control for form submitting

```
    <button class="search-btn" name="submit" type="submit">
      <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
```

or use `<input>` as submit button,

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

The main **problem** in your **code** is from PHP side, when you're checking for `$_POST['submit']` here,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ }
```

It's not entering in the `if()` statement, because it's not getting `$_POST['submit']` in you're code.

Please make sure you're following naming conversations for datatables & fields. So, please don't use **uppercase** & **space** in table/field name. Like you used in your query ("SELECT * FROM careers WHERE **Job Title** LIKE..."). Here **Job Title** should be **job_title**. (***Update in data-table too)

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM careers WHERE job_title LIKE '%$search%'");
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, Dipak. You are absolutely correct! changed now, and submitting...but still returning "No Results" even though I am searching for a known item in the database (grrr)

Comment: @wix updated the answer for your convenience.
if you think the answer correct, then please upvote/accept as a correct answer. So, it will be helpful for others facing the same issue. And thanks for the comment.

Answer (score -1):

there are no object assigned to the variable `$resultSet` in your code.
but you try to read it's property like `$resultSet->num_rows` this.

use `$result` insted of `$resultSet`

try this

```
$output=NULL;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//Connect to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "jj3wg2td_wix", "Sebastian!16", "jj3wg2td_careerslist");
    
$search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
    
//Query the database    
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM careers WHERE Job Title LIKE '%$search%'");
    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while($rows=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $jobTitle=$rows['Job Title'];
            $jobDesription=$rows['Job Description'];
                $salaryLow=$rows['Salary Low'];
                    $salaryHigh=$rows['Salary High'];
            
            $output .="Job Title:$jobTitle<br />
                        Job Description:$jobDesription<br />
                        Salary Low:$salaryLow<br />
                        Salary High:$salaryHigh<br />
                        <br />";
        }
    }
    else{
        $output="No results";   
    } 
}
```

Comment: While that does appear to be a secondary problem with the code the question asker will run into eventually ... the question asker isn't even getting to that point yet, which is the point of their current question.

Comment: reyad - yes I can Login and see the database

Comment: No...theyre fake names!

Comment: Hi Joy, Thanks for the code! Looking at it now, it manages to get down to the "No results" part of the code! I have removed the <a 'input area' and just stuck a standard submit/search button on for now. So, it would seem I am a bit further now (thank you!!!), but it still doesn't return results from table.

Comment: Here's the page if it helps - https://flighteducation.co.uk/Careers%20Connect.php